# C++: Replace object in std::vector 'in place' with a new object of same type but keep references to this object

Tags: c++

is it possible to replace an object in a `std::vector` with another object of same type and maintain any references to this object which was just replaced?

Let's say we have a

`std::vector<MyObj> objs`

and I want to replace an `MyObj`-object such that all references to this `MyObj` are still intact - is this possible?

Comment: It looks like you need a vector of pointers to these objects, not a vector of objects

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do it in general without some serious misuse of the language (e.g. using placement new in a situation for which it has not been designed). However, you can design `MyObj` class in a way that makes implementing this use case very straightforward. For example, if `MyObj` follows the [*Envelope and Letter Idiom*](https://www.panix.com/%7Eelflord/cpp/envelope/) which puts the implementation (the letter) and its wrapper (the envelope) into separate classes, you could make an array of wrappers, and replace their inner content without disturbing outside references:

```
// The real functionality goes here
struct MyObjImpl {
    void operation1() { ... }
    void operation2() { ... }
};

// This is a wrapper that forwards calls to the implementation,
// which can be switched at any time without disturbing references to MyObj
class MyObj {
    MyObjImpl* wrapped;
public:
    MyObj(MyObjImpl* rep) : wrapped(rep) {}
    void switch(MyObjectImpl* rep) {
        wrapped = rep;
    }
    void operation1() { wrapped->operation1(); }
    void operation2() { wrapped->operation2(); }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the only way to "replace" an object is to assign to it, then it is in fact unlikely that any references to the assigned-to object are invalidated in the first place.

That is, the answer is: You do not have to do anything special. All references to the "replaced" object remain intact.

Of course, there are other reasons that references to an object held in a `std::vector` are invalidated, but they do not happen during a well-behaved assignment to the object being held.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you will want to save states of replaced objects via `memento pattern` as it's called or just a `save state` control object. Ref to `memento` from `wiki` https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memento_pattern as it's lacking `C++` implementation it's simple to write. Also you may want to keep track of replaced objects so might extend it  a bit.